# Alternative ways of sending data securely over the public internet

Tags: php, http, encryption, ssl, https

I'm researching some options for securing the traffic from our mobile application, which currently is sending unencrypted data over an http request to our servers.

The most obvious option was to use HTTPS/SSL, however the mobile developer is reluctant to do this because of the extra network traffic (SSL Handshake) and the extra CPU load on the phone.

The only somewhat feasible option I can find is to use a pre-shared key to bypass the overhead of the handshake. So with using a standard HTTP POST, we'd send a cleartext API Key to identify the mobile app, probably as a HTTP Header, then encrypt the POST data with the PSK and send that to the server. The server'd lookup the PSK from the API Key, decrypt the POST, presumably do some validation to ensure it looks like good data, then pass it to the appropriate controller in our web app.

Is this even a plausible option? Are there better (or any non-SSL) alternatives?

Note that the mobile app is for both Blackberry and iPhone, and the serverside is LAMP[php].

Comment: Not using SSL for this is just silly.

Comment: So instead of using SSL, you want to implement your own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well,

what are you suggesting seems like roughly replicating the SSL. I don't mean the handshake routine, certificates etc, but in the end, you're still going to encrypt every request, back and forth, only with PSK instead of creating the sort-of PSK with SSL handshake. And that can be bad for your health.

It really depends on what is it you're trying to do. If you would do this only once in xx requests, it CAN be ok in terms of security and better in terms of performance. Or it may be very dangerous. Say I catch that API key, forge or just slightly modify the request and send it to you. What then?

I see the point with the overhead (and are you eliminating this, if you still encrypt your data, really??), but if a security is an issue to you, I would not try to reinvent the wheel here and use widely accepted and PROVEN standard. SSL doesn't solve everything, but you have a potential man-in-the-middle attack here.

Bottom line: Reimplementing, or replicating SSL is going to be hard, time consuming and costly, not to mention you will probably not make this secure on your first attempt. Don't go there, use SSL. It's exactly what you need

**Edit:** This link may prove useful as for SSL performance: [A Study of the Performance of SSL on PDAs](https://www.cs.indiana.edu/~shiny/pubs/gi09.pdf). Among there, you will find that the most expensive operation, the handshake, is not performed every time, usually.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information within the link - I'm hoping that this is enough information to dissuade the other developer from using a non-SSL solution.

Answer (score 3):

There was [a very similar question](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/9502/2435), migrated to Security.SE a few days ago.

- What makes you think that the handshake overhead you get with SSL/TLS will be more than the overhead of your own protocol?
- You can use [PSK with TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4279).
- Is your environment suited for the use of Pre-Shared Keys? (I mean, can you easily share your keys secretly within each instance of your mobile application).

Before trying to come up with an alternative to SSL/TLS, make measurements of the actual overhead incurred, and consider whether your new solution would suffer from the same overheads anyway. On the balance, probably not, and you're quite unlikely to come up with a solution as secure as SSL/TLS.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to implement Public/Private Key Encrpytion.

My best suggestion is to use SSL or at least the [OpenSSL libraries](http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php).  Implementing it yourself would be much more difficult as you would have to write your own methods to handle the VERY big integer math.